# Which API should I use to get "Buy box percentage", "session", "Average price" in Amazon MWS?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am using Amazon MWS API to list some merchant information. I would like to get the "buy box percentage," "session," and "average price" (average price for last seven days) for each of my products.

What is the correct API call to do that? I would specifically like to know how I can calculate the box percentage.

Answer (score 1):

The subscriptions API can send you notifications when an offer changes.

Then you can keep track of the time you had the buy box. Since these are 'push' notifications you should get a pretty accurate picture of the percentage.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html

> **IsBuyBoxWinner** : Indicates whether the offer is currently in the Buy Box. There can be up to two Buy Box winners at any time per ASIN,
>   one that is eligible for Prime and one that is not eligible for Prime.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this information is only accessible on the Seller Central website (and can be downloaded as CSV), but not through MWS.